Saving Render Result in Blender File - How can I save the Render Result within a Blender file to prevent it from disappearing after reopening?
How can I save the Render Result within a Blender file to prevent it from disappearing after reopening?
Every time I render an image in Blender, the Render Result disappears when I close and reopen the file. I find it inconvenient to lose the rendered image and have to re-render it or save/pack it every time.
Is there a way to automatically save the Render Result as part of the Blender file so that it stays there when I reopen the project? Also, I'm curious — why isn't this the default behavior in Blender?
I understand that saving the result as an external image file is an option, but I'm looking for a way to keep it embedded within the Blender file for easier workflow.
Also please note that I really do not want to create an addon/script just for saving the image object from the memory to the file itself.
Thanks,
Matej Zeman

You click this little button next to the image to protect it and embed it into the blend file. If you don't want to use scripting then I don't think you have any options. It would be pretty simple to create a custom operator that auto packs the render result though.

This is just how Blender works. Every object in your project is a data-block under the hood. Blender attempts to reuse data blocks wherever possible to reduce file size and memory usage. If a datablock doesn't have any users then its just "wasted space" and gets deleted when the file is closed.

I am sorry, but the Fake User did not work for me. I rendered image, closed the file, reopened and the image data has disappeared while Fake User still checked.
And for the automatization: If the fake user would work, then after checking File -> Defaults -> save as startup file on new file,  it will stay checked for all new projects.

The Fake User did save the data block, but did not keep the data itself. So under Blender File -> Images it is still there, but the image is empty.
